# Javascript closing a dropdown with document.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, dropdown, document

I have a dropdown dropdown using ul and li:

```
<img class="options_toggle" src="assets/down_arrow.png"onclick="toggle_display('options');"/>

<ul id="options" class="options_content hide">
      <li>
           option one
      </li>
</ul>
```

the options_toggle function swaps back and forth between the "hide" and "show" class in the options ul. Now I want to only hide it when the user clicks anywhere except the options toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
document.onclick = function(e) {

    // prevent the dropdown from closing instantly when you click the toggle to open it
    $(".options_toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // hide the dropdown
    $(".options_content").removeClass("show");
    $(".options_content").addClass("hide");
};
});
```

But the problem is that the first time they load the page they have to click somewhere once before clicking the toggle. After the first click it works fine, they just have to click twice at first which can be annoying.

Any ideas what it's doing and why it cancels or ignores the first toggle? Thanks.

Comment: .show {display:block;}
.hide {display:none;} these are my show and hide classes if it matters. There is probably a better way but this usually seems to work

Comment: Just show() and hide() or toggle method could have achieved it too. No need to write them specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually wrong to add an event handler inside another event handler. Just bind your `$(".options_toggle").click()` handler at top-level.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".options_toggle").click(function(e) {
    // prevent the dropdown from closing instantly when you click the toggle to open it
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    // hide the dropdown
    $(".options_content").removeClass("show");
    $(".options_content").addClass("hide");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey that helped... but only on one out of the 2 pages where I have this dropdown. The other page still runs the document click which instantly hides the dropdown after it's toggled on, even when i click on the .options_toggle. I'm halfway there but at least it can work